# Setting Up SSL AWS Between ELB and Relay Servers

Tags: amazon-web-services, encryption, amazon-elb, postfix-mta

I have three relay server instances that are currently sitting behind and ELB. The clients send their emails via postfix to the ELB, and the traffic is load balanced between the three relay servers before going outbound. I want to set up encryption between the ELB and the relay servers, so that the ELB listens on port 25 but forwards traffic on port 587 for example. How do I go about setting this up in AWS? Thanks for the help!

Best,
Ahmed

Comment: Are you referring in having SSL encryption in between, ELB and relay servers? I don't think you need to do it to secure the connection. The recommended approach is to keep ELB in public subnet with security group rule in opening port 25 publically and Relay servers in private subnet having security group rule to only receive inbound traffic from the ELB's security group. ELB can forward the traffic to the Relay servers targeted group with port mapping to 587.

Comment: Sounds like something I'll try. Then I would just need to setup certs on my relay certs, and configure postfix to use SSL.